plural forms of adjective nouns
Why do we say "apple trees" but "liberal arts colleges"?
I have seen discussion like Nouns of plural form preceding another noun but I don't get a very definitive answer. It seems like one suggestion is that if the "field" itself is a plural form, then we put plural nouns as adjective?

There are lots of existing questions e.g. When are attributive nouns plural?, Which form should be used for at­tribu­tive nouns like “stu­dent union”: sin­gu­lar or plu­ral, or pos­ses­sive sin­gu­lar or pos­ses­sive plu­ral?. But there is no universal rule. If you want a definitive answer, quit studying language and become a mathematician.

Those are not adjectives. They're nouns that modify other nouns. That does not make them adjectives.

Liberal arts is a course of study. It needs the s... liberal arts college,  economics class, humanities program, linguistics major...

In English only the main noun is pluralized when converting to the plural form. Any modifying noun is not altered along with the main noun. The main noun of "apple tree" is "tree", and "apple" is the modifying noun, specifying what kind of tree it is. Likewise "college" is the main noun and "liberal arts" the modifying noun phrase, specifying what it teaches. So:

One apple tree; two apple trees


One liberal arts college; two liberal arts colleges

The confusion probably arises from the fact that "liberal arts" is a phrase referring to a multiplicity of subjects, and hence is inherently plural. This is unrelated to whether the main noun is singular or plural.
You can talk about a "liberal art college", which strictly means a college that teaches art (the singular subject, i.e. painting, drawing etc.) and is also liberal. The plural would be "two liberal art colleges". The similarity of the two means they are sometimes mistakenly used in place of each other.

This is an oversimplification of the bigger, thornier topic of attributive nouns. A shoe store sells shoes and a parts department sells parts.

Yes, just like "apple" is singular and "arts" is plural. But neither of those are affected by whether store or department are singular or plural

The fact that attributive nouns are usually singular-form has been discussed on ELU at length. OP seems to conflate 'plural-form attributive nouns' with 'variable -form attributive nouns, pluralising with the head noun'.  The  question  'Why / in what cases are plural-form attributive nouns used?' is addressed at Which form should be used for attributive nouns like student union / students union / students' union ....

Regardless, this answer basically covers it. The Brits drive me crazy with: the drugs policy. :)

@Lambie Searches turn up both "drug statute(s)" and "drugs statute(s)" in the US.

@DjinTonic That's the problem with internet searches, you can't tell usage. It has to be internalized. Anyway, my term was drugs policy versus drug policy. Not laws.

I can't say for sure, but to my best knowledge it's probably due to the fact that a tree is a countable noun which can be simply expressed in plural form, whereas 'arts' is a field and is abstract, so the 's' addition seems to be valid, the same way as 'the field of mathematics' seems right.
